# Filtering div's on page using drop down list jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filtering

I have a page with lot of similar `<div>` elements on it and I need to allow users to filter it by selecting value from drop-down list. 
Is there any simple jquery plugin to do that? I found http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/ but it is too complicated, I need just a simple filtering by drop-down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on your filtering logic, but something like this?

```
<select id="sel">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
</select>

<div class="filt one">one</div>
<div class="filt one">one</div>
<div class="filt one">one</div>
<div class="filt one">one</div>
<div class="filt one">one</div>
<div class="filt one">one</div>
<div class="filt two">two</div>
<div class="filt two">two</div>
<div class="filt two">two</div>
<div class="filt two">two</div>
<div class="filt three">three</div>

<script> 
$("#sel").on("change", function(){
$(".filt").show();
$("."+$(this).val()).hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I thought it would be more complicated. Thank you!